# How to trigger mouseover programmatically? (orce hover state not working)

Tags: javascript, events, developer-tools

On this page: https://turbo-theme-seoul.myshopify.com/ the drop-down menus appear when mouseover the corresponding menu item. In order to inspect the HTML elements of the drop-down menus, I need to force them to display. Normally this can be done by forcing the state of the parent menu item to be `:hover` in developer tools, but in this case it doesn't work. I guess the drop-down is triggered by javascript instead of CSS. How can I make this drop-down appear programmatically without having to move my mouse over it? I tried

```
$($0).hover()
```

and

```
$0.dispatchEvent('mouseover')
```

on the parent menu item, they are both not working. It seems to me that 'mouseover' event can't be triggered programmatically. How do I do this then? PS: I know I can just find the drop-down menu in HTML and remove "display:none" from them, I just want to know if there is any way to trigger the mouseover event and let the dropdown menu appear programmatically for learning purpose.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't want to help someone reverse engineer someone else's website.

Comment: @Jorg, Haven't you even seen a cool technique and wanted to figure out how it was done?

Comment: @Steve all the time, and if I asked you how it worked i would learn *nothing*. consequently, i'm not going to debug it because you asked me to, because you would learn nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As the jquery official document says:

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. This allows the user to use jQuery's various toggle methods within the handler or to respond differently within the handler depending on the event.type.

so the hover event is consist of `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` event, so you can't trigger the hover event programmatically since you can't trigger `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` at the same time.. So you should use `.mouseenter()` to show your drop-down, and use `.mouseleave()` to hide it.

Comment: I did `$($0).mouseenter()`, it is not working, the dropdown won't show.

Comment: @shenkwen What's `$0`? Try `$('.mega-menu-parent').mouseenter()`, and it works.